# C#: Error with PivotItem creation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

After `PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();` I'm getting  `Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`. What should it be? I'm pretty confused of it.

Code:

```
foreach (Source source in sources)
{
    PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem(); /* At this point it falls. */
    pivotItem.Header = source.Name;
    pivotItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, 0);

    ListView listView = new ListView();
    listView.ItemsSource = source.Articles;
    listView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["MainItemTemplate"];
    listView.ItemClick += OpenArticle_ItemClick;
    listView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
    listView.IsItemClickEnabled = true;

    pivotItem.Content = listView;
    pvtMain.Items.Add(pivotItem);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that without any additional context ("error code or any details") we can help you.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Please, review my edited post with error details.

Comment: What is `PivotItem`? In what context are you calling this code? Don't just post the exception error message, post an [MCVE].

Comment: @JanChalupa That is not much more helpful without the actual code that causes this exception - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also there seems to be a lot of info over the net about the `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD` hresult.

Comment: OK, another edit. :)

Comment: @JanChalupa It would have been much better if you'd read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and added all the relevant information initially. Because even now your question lacks the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it even lacks the full exception stack trace. I recommend you to read and follow the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) - it will greatly improve your experience on [SO], though it requires a bit of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception, you seem to be trying to create a new `PivotItem` in a thread other than the UI thread. You are only allowed to interact with the UI elements in the UI thread.

You're probably calling this code from an event handler that wasn't triggered from a UI event. You should be able to resolve the issue by using the [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher.aspx) to switch back to the UI thread:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    foreach (Source source in sources)
    {
        PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem(); /* At this point it falls. */
        pivotItem.Header = source.Name;
        pivotItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, 0);

        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = source.Articles;
        listView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["MainItemTemplate"];
        listView.ItemClick += OpenArticle_ItemClick;
        listView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
        listView.IsItemClickEnabled = true;

        pivotItem.Content = listView;
        pvtMain.Items.Add(pivotItem);
    }
});
```